# How do I set value node to #frame using python

Tags: python, animation, geometry-nodes, drivers

when adding a Value node through the geometry node tree editor I can enter `#frame` in the value field to have it synced up with the animation frame index (for procedural animation etc.)

[image]

However, I haven't found a way to add this kind of node with python. I was expecting to be able to do something like this:

```
modifier.node_group.nodes["Value"].outputs[0].default_value = "#frame"
```

But then I just get

```
TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: NodeSocketFloat.default_value expected a float type, not str
```

Is there any way to make use of this feature using only scripting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a driver from nodes

```
import bpy

md = bpy.context.object.modifiers["GeometryNodes"]
dr = md.node_group.nodes["Value"].outputs[0].driver_add("default_value")
dr.driver.expression = "frame"
bpy.context.view_layer.update()
```

Comment: thanks! For some reason driver_add doesn't show up in `node_group.nodes["Value"].outputs[0].__dir__()` so I was unable to find it